# Is possible install ubuntu 13.04 on toshiba m40?

Tags: 13.04, toshiba

When I tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 but it was terribly slow. I love Ubuntu but I need to know if the computer can support the OS or not.

Comment: What are the specs of this computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask if its possible, then the answer is yes, you can.
But looking at your laptop's specs i would not recommend it.
Instead you can use a less resource intensive distro like Lubuntu which would run well on older hardware.
http://lubuntu.net/[1](http://lubuntu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

According to Ubuntu Community the basic system requirements for Ubuntu are as follows

**Ubuntu Desktop Edition**

1.700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)

2.512 MiB RAM (system memory)

3.5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

4.VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution

5.Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

6.Internet access is helpful

See if your system meets the above requirements and if doesn't you can opt for **lubuntu** or **xubuntu**

See the link below

[Basic System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)